# How to change character inserted between joined lines?

Tags: vim

Normally, for this sort of thing I would use a visual range and pipe to `tr`, but there must be a way to use the `join` command (`J`) to insert `,` between lines.  That is, change:

```
foo
bar
```

into

```
foo,bar
```

Is there a setting to make `J` insert a character other than a space between lines?  The B and M options in `fo-table` allow me to change the way spaces are handled, but there doesn't seem to be a way to change the character used.

Comment: Impossible, I think, it's always a space or 2 spaces. Use `:s/$/,/`

Answer (score 2):

Use mappings:

```
" for normal mode (with [count] support)
nnoremap <silent>J @='Jr,'<CR>

" for visual mode
vnoremap <silent>J :<C-U>if line("'>") > line("'<") \| '<,'>-1s?\n?,? \| endif<CR>
```

Otherwise, you can only choose a number of spaces: `set nojoinspaces` - always single space (otherwise, two spaces after `.?!`); `gJ` - no spaces.